# Wordpress running on the Docker: Error establishing a database connection

Tags: wordpress, docker

I try run Wordpress on the Docker. If I try using simple command lika:

```
docker run wordpress
```

Wordpress running correctly. Other way that it's not enough for me. I don't have craditionals to db, where can I edit the code, etc. Co I tryed using docker-compose.yml from documentation:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  wordpress:
  db:
```

I use `docker-compose up -d` and this containers started but when I go to `localhost:8080` I has an error

```
Error establishing a database connection
```

For me is no different that I run wordpress via one command or docker-compose. I need to run this and I need to edit this (I want to learn make a plugins and templates). How is the simplest way to run Wordpress via Docker?

@Update

When i run docker dompose console return something like this:

```
[+] Running 11/11
 ⠿ db Pulled                                                   27.3s
   ⠿ 7b1a6ab2e44d Already exists                                0.0s
   ⠿ 034655750c88 Pull complete                                 4.3s
   ⠿ f0b757a2a0f0 Pull complete                                 4.7s
   ⠿ 5c37daf8b6b5 Pull complete                                 5.0s
   ⠿ b4cd9409b0f6 Pull complete                                 5.1s
   ⠿ dbcda06785eb Pull complete                                 6.2s
   ⠿ a34cd90f184c Pull complete                                 6.4s
   ⠿ fd6cef4ce489 Pull complete                                 7.1s
   ⠿ 3cb89a1550ea Pull complete                                21.7s
   ⠿ df9f153bd930 Pull complete                                21.7s
[+] Running 5/5
 ⠿ Network test-wp_default        Created                       0.1s
 ⠿ Volume "test-wp_db_data"       Created                       0.0s
 ⠿ Volume "test-wp_wp_data"       Created                       0.0s
 ⠿ Container test-wp-wordpress-1  Started                       0.7s
 ⠿ Container test-wp-db-1         S...                          0.7s
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to [`expose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#expose) the database ports:

```
services:
  db:
    expose:
      - "3306"
```

**NOTE:** If you need access to the database directly, you'll need to use `ports` instead of `expose`.

Comment: I tryed (I updated my post) but effect is this same.

Comment: Two things: 1. Can you share the source of the docker compose file? 2. Does Wordpress automatically setup the schema when it first connects to the database?

Comment: 1. I shared in my post, 2 I don't think so. Terminal doesn't return information about it. It doesn't matter which docker-file I use. Everytime is this same. I updated my post and I add what console returning.